# Apply CSS hover state to defined area only

Tags: html, css

I've taken a break from hand coding and this is kinda stumping me at the moment. I have a simple website with an entry page featuring two large buttons, splitting the width of the page.

http://www.jse-interiordesign.com/

My client now wants to retain that size for the buttons, but to now only apply the hover state to the boxes around the "Hospitality" and "Residential" areas. Is there a quick and easy way to do this with CSS? The page has different setups for mobile, etc. that I don't want to alter at all as it was built by someone else.

Here's the current CSS:

```
div.left_link a{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
/*  background-color: transparent; */
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 100011;
    background-color: #FFF; 
    opacity: 0; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    cursor: pointer; 

}
div.left_link a:hover{
    z-index: 100012 !important;
    background-color: #FFF !important;
    opacity: 0.5 !important; 
}
div.right_link a{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
/*  background-color: transparent; */
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 100011;
    background-color: #FFF; 
    opacity: 0; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    cursor: pointer; 
}

div.right_link a:hover{
    z-index: 100012 !important;
    background-color: #FFF !important;
    opacity: 0.5 !important; 
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help I can get!

Comment: Please add meaningful code here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: The issue is the page in question is two images wrapped in anchors. I mean, yeah you can make a block element, size it and position it absolute to the boxes, and give it an opacity on hover with a white background. But I think it would be less work to just make it right....

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that if you were to use :

```css
specific_div_name:hover elementyouwanttochange {
    z-index: 100012 !important;
    background-color: #FFF !important;
    opacity: 0.5 !important; 
}
```

that would work. It would mean that if your element was hovered, then this element would do the following.